# How to add custom javascript in wordpress posts area?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to add a JavaScript quiz in WordPress. I have tried this method for  using is it in HTML way. But its not working.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rpscadda/pkbnte3o/2/) is this java script quiz link.

Comment: You need to have code when you link to a jsfiddle...

Comment: i have added all javascript, jquery and css fies  in wordpress post area with html code but there is nothing to show, only post title is showing there.

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple shortcode if you have access to the wordpress template. For example using the following code (note tested):

```
class MyShortCodes {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init() {
        add_shortcode('my_javascript', array($this, 'my_javascript'));
        add_shortcode('my_javascript_file', array($this, 'my_javascript_file'));
    }

    public function my_javascript($attributes, $content = null) {
        return ''; // REPLACE THIS BY YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODE.
    }

    public function my_javascript_file($attributes, $content = null) {
        // Except for pasting all the JavaScript into the post's content,
        // enqueue the JavaScript file here and only add a call to it in the
        // post's content above.
        wp_enqueue_script('my_javascript_file', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/my_javascript_file.js');
    }
}

new MyShortCodes();
```

Place this file in your wordpress template's `include` directory and include it in `functions.php`:

```
require_once 'includes/my_shortcodes.php';
```

As you can see, there are two options: You can either paste the full JavaScript code into the body of the post by calling the `[my_javascript]` shortcode (and editing the `my_javascript` function to contain all your code), or you can enqueue a JavaScript file (e.g. `quiz.js` in your template) containing your code encapsulated as an object or a function using `[my_javascript_file]` (it will then be included once, even if more posts are displayed), and only include a small JavaScript snippet in each post through `[my_javascript]` (with a simple call to the functions provided in `quiz.js`).

Also have a short look into the shortcode documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API.